# How do i parse live csv data from a serial port in Python?

Tags: python, csv, parsing, pyserial

I am very new in python and I'm trying to create a program which takes live input from a COM port (connected to a wind detector) and parses the live data into a more human-friendly output. The data currently received from the port is in the csv format:

```
Q,060,000.10,M,00,19
```

"Q" is the current node address,

"060" is the wind direction,

"000.10" is the wind speed,

"M" is the unit (m/s),

"00" is the status and the last number is the checksum.

I was able to get python to print out the continuous data via Pyserial readline() however it's in the default format which is not what I want. I tried using csv.reader to parse and read the code however I don't seem to be able to get it printing in the right format. I tried implementing csv.reader into it but the results separates every single item as a new line.

This is the code I have for the reading and parsing.

```
while True:
    data = ser.readline().decode('ascii')
    csvReader = csv.reader(data, delimiter=',')
    for row in csvReader:
        print(row)
```

The result I'm getting now is:

```
['\x02']
['Q']
['', '']
['', '']
['0']
['0']
['0']
['.']
['0']
['1']
['', '']
['M']
['', '']
['0']
['0']
```

I am trying to get the final output similar to this:

```
"Wind Direction is 60deg. 
Wind Speed is 0.10 m/s. 
The current status is Ok"
```

Comment: It looks like the `readline()` is not working.  If you remove the last three lines of code and instead do: `print('>>{}<<'.format(data))`, what does it look like?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
while True:
    data = ser.readline().decode('ascii')
    # print(data)  # uncomment this line to debug the coming data
    node, direction, speed, M, status = data.split(',')

    print(f"Wind Direction is {direction} deg.") 
    print(f"Wind Speed is {speed} m/s.")
```